# Having trouble implementing TikTok's Login Kit on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, oauth, rubygems, tiktok

All of the tutorials and Stack Overflow answers I've been seeing have addressed production environments, but haven't addressed any redirects and callbacks for a local environment. I'd love some help on how to do this locally!

Attaching pics of my current TikTok Developer application configuration and the error page I get from TikTok — all with fake tld & query params

The `redirect_uri` query param I'm using on `localhost`:

```
waitlist.localhost:3000/auth/tiktok/callback
```

[image: TikTok Developer Callback Settings]
[image: TikTok Auth Error Page]

Comment: Not sure if that helps but it might be tiktok that does not allow for redirections to localhost, as this might be a vulnerability and potentially exploitet. I don't know enough about this to tell you for sure but I cannot find a obvious typo/bug in your posting.

Comment: Another way of handling 2 environements is passing an optional query param to all requests, e.g. `environement=dev`, and then handling it on your backend (if query param environment=dev exists, redirect to localhost:3000/... otherwise to waitlist.ex.com

Comment: Best-practice is to always use a real domain with SSL and try match the live environment in order to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Did you ever get this working, i have tried 127.0.0.1 and ngrok with no luck

Answer (score 1):

At the moment tiktok do not support localhost as callback url or I just don't know how to =)
You can put record on `/etc/hosts` like
`127.0.0.1  waitlist.ex.com`

And then setup your ruby server with ssl or just spin up nginx with ssl and proxy to your app.

I used second option for testing tiktok oauth locally

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, I use ngrok to open a tunnel to my local dev env. If you pay for it you can set some fix domains that you can put into the redirection domain list in TikTok.

Comment: I have been using ngrok but its still not accepting my redirecturi.   Do you have more information on what you set in the dev console for tiktok and what redirect uri you sent to make the request?

Comment: For your TikTok app, did you set the ngrok domain in the `Redirect domain` section in the `Login Kit` section? Don't forget to include the subdomain part as well e.g.: yyy.ngrok.io You can have an app for staging and an another one for production.